# How do you use ProtectedBrowserStorage and BlazorServer AspNet Authentication for Cookie based login?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, blazor-server-side

I have a system that is creating claims and adding them to authentication manually on a BlazorServer using AspNet Authentication.

```
// Maps internal User object into an IdentityUser object
// TODO: Use mapping library
var blazorUser = UserOpenIDToIdentityUser.ConvertUserOpenIDToIdentityUser(user);

var principal = await _signinManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(blazorUser);

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            principal.Claims,
            Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        );
principal = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

_signinManager.Context.User = principal;
_hostAuthentication.SetAuthenticationState(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(principal)));
```

This works but if the user refreshes it is gone, as signalR is server side so can't write the cookie to a users browser. One solution I read was to use javascript on the page to save the cookie, but I would much rather just use the new LocalStorage for Asp.Net-Core(As I know the older Blazored had an option for this also). Now this is where it gets fuzzy for me. I need to have something like

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "MyScheme";
}).AddCookie("MyScheme", options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "CookieName";
});
```

that uses LocalStorage/sessionStorage.

How would I specify which one I want? If I can't have authentication/cookies write to that do I just load the user in from it if there is no current user(I don't want to/wouldn't be the best to use javascript)?

Comment: Been studying and realized that cookie storage is a separate thing, and loads before the render call, where local/session storage isn't(at least not accessible before render). What this means is that if the page is refreshed the user check won't happen until after it is loaded. So manually checking if there is a user and then loading them back in can work. I am missing how to make it work smoothly with everything else, as my relogging in the user vs it checking itself is annoying, but maybe just what is needed.